# Could the antimatter from the Big Bang have gone in the opposite direction in time?

Tags: big-bang, antimatter

I am thinking, that the missing antimatter that was created at the Big Bang can be accounted for if we consider that it went the opposite direction in time (into the negatives)

Comment: @StephenG This is not a duplicate of that question. People have proposed bidirectional big bang models where there is a second region at $t<0$ (with a reversed thermodynamic arrow of time), and one of the justifications is that they supposedly explain the matter/antimatter asymmetry. It's been mentioned on Physics SE before. I'm failing to find any examples at the moment - "bidirectional" is apparently the wrong keyword.

Comment: @benrg It is a well known idea indeed +1

Comment: The term you are looking for this general issue is [Baryon Asymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_asymmetry).  The concept you are discussing is the idea of a *mirror anti-universe*.  There is AFAIK no evidence supporting this  idea.  No idea if there were previous questions here.

Comment: Thank you StephenG. The link to Baryon Asymmetry answered my question.